# Use buildx build linux/arm64 in docker-compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I can build my dockerfile separately using following command:

```
docker buildx build --platform linux/arm64 -t testbuild .
```

now I want to use buildx in docker-compose file, but how, and how to say I want to use the arm64 architecture? This is the structure when I use the normal build.

```
testbuild:
build: …/testbuild
image: testbuild
```

Does anybody know?

Answer (score 12):

You can use buildx in docker-compose by setting ENV variable `COMPOSE_DOCKER_CLI_BUILD=1`, also if buildx is not set as default, you should add `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1`:

```
COMPOSE_DOCKER_CLI_BUILD=1 DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker-compose build
```

Comment: I think that enables Build*Kit*, not buildx

Comment: Agree with @scytale, COMPOSE_DOCKER_CLI_BUILD=1 DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 enable buildx but they do not trigger the proper cross platform build. --platform does not work with docker-compose versions higher than 2.4

Answer (score 9):

In docker-compose v2.4 was add attribute `platform`. Official documentation [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#platform).

Example:

```
version: '2.4'

services:
  testbuild:
    build: .../testbuild
    image: testbuild
    platform: linux/arm64/v8
```

P.S. Idk why, but it work only in docker-compose version 2.4

P.S.S About `dockerx` in docker-compose, he's not there. I think because `dockerx` is [experimental feature](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/buildx/) in docker engine.

Answer (score 6):

Try the `docker buildx bake` command. Official [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/buildx_bake/) says:

> Use the -f / --file option to specify the build definition file to use. The file can be a Docker Compose, JSON or HCL file.

It also lets you pass the names of the targets to build, to build only specific targets.

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
COMPOSE_DOCKER_CLI_BUILD=1 \
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 \
DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM=linux/amd64 \
docker-compose build
```

`DOCKER_BUILDKIT`

Enable (1) or disable (0) BuildKit builds

`DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM`

Set the default platform for commands that take the `--platform` flag

`COMPOSE_DOCKER_CLI_BUILD`

Configure whether to use the Compose built-in python client (0) for building images or the native docker cli (1). By default, Compose uses the docker CLI to perform builds, which allows you to use BuildKit to perform builds.